# My fixed background made scrolling the site very slow, what can I do to improve it?

Tags: css, background, vertical-scrolling, smooth-scrolling

I changed the background of my discussion forum using the CSS below

http://forum.antinovaordemmundial.com

```
html {
    background: url(http://antinovaordemmundial.com/mystuff/logo_blog.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-image: url(http://antinovaordemmundial.com/mystuff/logo_blog.jpg);
    background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
    background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    background-origin: initial;
    background-clip: initial;
    background-color: initial;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The image is 1600x711 and 88k. The scrolling of the pages are now very slow. Is the CSS problematic or the image should be smaller somehow?

Edit: I tried changing to:

```
body {        
    color: #000;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center; /* IE 5 fix */
    line-height: 1.4;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-clip: initial;
    background-color: #51010E;
    background-image: url(http://antinovaordemmundial.com/mystuff/logo_blog.jpg);
    background-origin: initial;
    background-position: initial initial;
    background-repeat: initial initial;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

But it is still very slow on scrolling.

Comment: I'm using chrome, but I tried also with firefox.

Comment: not slow or laggy for me (Chrome 13)

Comment: I'm getting some lag in Chrome 13, and its causing a lot of CPU use when scrolling. Does the problem go away if you remove the background image?

Comment: +1 for high CPU usage in Chrome 13--it's eating 100% of one of my cores when scrolling

Comment: Also, from a design perspective, it seems like it might be a bad idea to have a resizing background when the width of the content remains the same. It looks like your trying to make the middle area glow white using the background. which would not work correctly unless they size dynamically in unison.

Comment: I cleaned up the middle area to try to decrease the image size...

Comment: Jcubed, I removed the image the changed the background color, that solved the lag. A shame though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem goes away for me when I remove the `background-size` property. I think it was the scaling of the large image that was causing the problem. If that doesn't work, just remove the background image altogether. However, I've never heard of a large background image causing lag before.

Comment: The `background-size` property is certainly making an impact, but the site still seems to scroll slowly with it disable.  I'd say it's a 100% improvement, but there's still an issue.

Comment: @STW: What if you remove the image entirely?

Comment: Removing the image appears to completely resolve the issue, regardless of the `background-size` being enabled or disabled.  However, it wouldn't seem to do much for the OP's question ;-)

Comment: I removed the image altogether, although I would had prefered to keep it. I will test without the background-size property.

Comment: Is there a suitable replacement for background-size?  I have the same lag issue when scrolling and am also using large images at about the same size and k-weight

Comment: It's probably not the size of the image itself, but I would guess that browsers are for some reason, resizing the image every frame. Just a guess.

Comment: This is no solution. "Remove your code and it will work", come on.

Comment: my image's size was very big , so when i resized it, it's working fine. without removing the background-size: "cover".

Answer (score 18):

I thought I would just contribute here. Rather than use background-attachment: fixed; use :before and position: fixed; problem sorted. I ran into this same problem.

Read more here: http://fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property

Comment: Awesome solution. no jquery, just pure css3!

Comment: This doesn't work with multiple elements using background-attachment

Comment: This comes as the first Google result for me now and it worked perfectly. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Found this solution as well. I have a background per section, which gives each transparent bit its own fixed background as you scroll by. Unfortunately this trick doesn't work in that instance.

Comment: This is the best solution imo

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and solved it using this jQuery plugin :
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/

It doesn't use any CSS3 property but it works fine and doesn't have any performance issue on Chrome 13 or Firefox 6.

Comment: Yep, loved not blocking my page rendering with the css and background.  +1 and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Also, applying the following style to the `html` tag improves the frame rate significantly in WebKit browsers, Chrome included:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

This works in all cases with (large) background photos and choppy scrolling as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is actually with the background-attachment fixed value if you change it to background-attachment: scroll for mobile devices it should fix the lag.

Answer (score 1):

make the background-size to `99.9%` not `100%` or cover in the case of the fixed attachment

```css
background-size : 99.9%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Compressing the image (reducing  the size), solved my issue, I highly recommend using a tool like [Radical Image Optimization Tool (RIOT)](http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/), very effective and easy.

On linux, this can be done using [GIMP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp/) , you can also remove image's metadata to reduce the size, use tool like [exiftool](https://askubuntu.com/a/260811/699506).

Answer (score 0):

Changing your image file type to SVG significantly improved the performance of my site when experiencing the same issue!

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `background-repeat` property if you have included and don't use 100% value for `background-size`..

```
background-size: 0 - 99.9%;
```