# How can I prevent background-attachment:fixed; from lagging my website?

Tags: css

I was using background-attachment:fixed; on my website but it was causing Chrome to lag for some users. Is there a way to have the same effect without causing lag? Lag has stopped since I removed it but I much preferred the look for my site.

Comment: May be reading this helps?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033979/my-fixed-background-made-scrolling-the-site-very-slow-what-can-i-do-to-improve

Comment: @Quincy, I did see this. Couldn't figure any alternative methods from it. Only way I have found is to change the attachment to scroll (default).

Answer (score 3):

It is actually a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90637) since 2011, the `background-attachment:fixed` rule causes the browser to repaint the background on every scroll, which is an issue on large screens and Retina displays.

There is a workaround, add this rule to your css stylesheet:

```
html{
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: This seems to stop the "background-attachment:fixed" rule applying.

Comment: One thing, make sure your image size is not large. I have tried adding a 500kb image as background and fixed attached. It was lagging even I have added translate3d.