# Website lag on scroll

Tags: html, css

I'am busy with my website, and now I have a issue.

When i scroll down to my contact page, my browser starts to lagg, because i have a background image with the property scroll, and size cover.

So i googled a bit and the result was that the property cover causes the laggs.

How can i fix this? I need my background size covered because i have my website responsive

My code:

```
background-attachment: scroll,  fixed;
background-color: #666;
background-image: url("../images/black.png"), url("../images/bg-footer.jpg");
background-position: center,    center center;
background-size: cover, cover;
```

Comment: Have you compressed your images at all? That would probably be the place to start.

Comment: Yes, the image is only 500kb

Comment: Have you tried adding `transform: rotateX(0deg);` to force it into a separate layer and hand off its drawing to the GPU?

Comment: I can't follow you there haha

Comment: If you use `transform:`, you force the drawing of your background to be done by your GPU instead of your CPU, which could speed up things.

Comment: Anyone have an answer?

Comment: Please put some code on JsFiddle.

Comment: `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-moz-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);`

correctly forces hardware-acceleration

Comment: Where do i have to place it? In the div I use for the background?

Comment: @josh_bailey4 - you are a god. This kind of hardware acceleration is what I needed for a LONG time. Many thanks! Also, if not for Tom and somethinghere, I wouldn't have viewed more comments and seen your comment. Upvotes for all of you c:

Comment: @josh_bailey4 is this still valid in 2022 ?

Answer (score 1):

Can i ask why you need to use background-attachment: scroll at all?

You have set the background image to cover the full width of its container, which means it's not going to change position on scroll anyway.

You are forcing the browser to recalculate the image size whenever you scroll the mouse, causing the lag.

You could also try using other properties like contain or 100% width to fix your image.

Comment: The images resizes to the full size of the width. Then it has to scroll with. Found my inspiration at: http://html5up.net/alpha

Comment: yep, like i said above, this is becasue the browser is dynamically calculating the full screen size and applying it to the image whenever you change the screen position. 

This means scrolling down makes the browser perform this complex calculation many times a second. 

The answer is not not use background cover with background scroll. 

These answers should help too: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869086/poor-performance-of-chrome-using-background-size-cover

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033979/my-fixed-background-made-scrolling-the-site-very-slow-what-can-i-do-to-improve